# Rewrite urls depending on the host

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a Nginx server which serves a Symfony app.
But this app may receive requests from different hosts (which are for now simulated in `/etc/hosts`), and for each host, there is a kind of cache directory located in the `public` directory, having their own name:

```
|-src
|-var
|-...
|-public
|   |-host1.com
|   |   |-file1
|   |   |-file2
|   |-host2.com
|   |   |-file1
|   |   |-...
```

URIs can be of the following form (please note the absence of the subdirectory name):

```
https://host1.com/file1
```

In this case, I want Nginx to check if the `public/host1.com/file1` exists. So I need to setup a kind of rewrite rule from `/file1` to `/host1.com/file1`.
If the file exists, Nginx has to serve it. But if not (i.e. `https://host1.com/file53`), I want Nginx to redirect to the Symfony app, so that this one can generate the missing file, and serve it.

How can I do this with Nginx?

Here is my try. Without the 3 lines below the comment, it is working as a classic server.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/project/public;

    location / {
        ##############################################
        # Here is my try, but Nginx crashes with this:
        ##############################################
        if ($host = "host1.com") {
            try_files /host1.com$uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass myapp:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|eof|woff|ttf)$ {
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            expires 30d;
            access_log off;
        }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    rewrite_log on;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log notice;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

Comment: The way to handle multiple hosts efficiently, is separate `server` blocks - but have you tried using `try_files /$host$uri ...` and losing the `if` block?

Comment: No, it doesn't work; for now i will try other alternatives, but comments are welcome of course

Comment: If the number of hosts being served is rather limited, then separate `server` block for each would be the best (and securest) approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, using different `server` blocks was the solution.

I also had problems with the following part, which was blocking all the image requests without logging it, which had caused misunderstandings in my debugging process:

```
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|eof|woff|ttf)$ {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```